# New version code not recognized when building Android project

Tags: android, build, version, google-play, apk

I recently completed an update to my app, so I built it and tried to upload it to the market. I incremented the version code to the next number (7), but when trying to upload it I am told that I still need to change the version code because it is 6. I changed it for the manifest in my project, and I even tried changing it to 8 but I got the same error. I've tried building without proguard, saving the apk to a different location, deleting the previous apk before building it, but I still receive the same error. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure your apk include the new manifest? Can you provide your manifest to us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Eclipse? Clean your project and Build again.

IntelliJ? Build > Rebuild Project.

Likely there's something cached, and it's neglecting to recompile that file for some reason.